# How can I import and use method describe using require js in normal js file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have one file button.js that look like this:

```
function confirmDeleteDefaultCallback (ev) {
// window.location = ev.data.url;
this.currentRequest = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ev.data.url,  ///cd/asset/delete/id/' + assetId
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(AssetsView); 
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("yep error");
    }
});
$('#modal').modal('hide');
```

};

I have another file in a different directory called assets.js which look like this:

```
const INITIAL_PAGINATION = {
    current_page: 0,
    total_pages: 0,
    per_page: 15,
    links: {}
};

define([
    'fancyBox',
    'models/assetSearch/asset',
    'marionette',
    'marionette.handlebars',
    'views/assetSearch/asset'
], function($, AssetModel, Marionette, MarionetteHandlebars, assetView) {
    var AssetsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        "view-admin": false,
        "can-download": false,
        "can-download-low-res": false,

        testggg: function() {
            console.log("\nggg\n");
        },
  });
  return AssetsView;
}
);
```

My question is, how can I call testggg function from button.js

I tried googling and everything but I have no idea what to search since I am a newbie. Looks like a simple task but I seem to stuck in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't use require('./AssetsView') in your normal js file?

Comment: I know. chrome complain about it. Is there a way to use assets.js file in button.js.

Answer (score 0):

> Use 
>   [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Please not that JS importing and exporting is not natively supported in any browser. Use some JS bundler like browserify or Webpack (webpack is a bit difficult to get started). It lets you build your code in modular way and then finally bundles it all up in one JS file that you can attach in your HTML as an external script.